# Pass string value as a type

Tags: c#

I have some enumerations, like that: OneEnum, TwoEnum, ThreeEnum, etc.
Depending on the user's input I want to print the content of the corresponding enumeration.

I use a foreach like the one below to do that.

```
foreach(OneEnum i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(OneEnum)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
}
```

Since I have many different enumerations, I am trying to create a way to do that without having many if statements where I check the enumeration type.

At some point I get a string like that `enumType = "OneEnum"` or `enumType = "TwoEnum"` etc, which is the type of the enumeration.

Is there a way to pass the string's value as the enumeration type in the foreach?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`Type.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach(Enum i in Enum.GetValues(Type.GetType("Your.Namespace.OneEnum"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/KXFEX78943

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's was I was looking for. I was doing the same mistake with OneEnum instead of Enum and i wasn't adding the namespace in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the type by reflection:

```
foreach(Enum i in Enum.GetValues(Type.GetType(typeName)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
}
```

You have to make sure though that `typeName` is an assembly-qualified name.

Comment: Well, same answer as Jamies

Comment: ...with the mistake I originally made of still hardcoding `OneEnum` instead of `Enum` in the `foreach`

Comment: I fixed that problem, too. It's great to see how my reply, which I started to write before @Jamiec's reply was sent does receive a negative score, while the other doesn't.

Comment: @Sefe Thank you too. I accepted Jamiec's since it was the first one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: So what if it's redundand? I didn't know about the other reply when I posted it and why should I delete it when it's correct? I don't care about acceptance, first come, first served.

Comment: @Bauss FYI, the downvotes on this answer were more to do with it being incorrect. When it was corrected, all of those downvotes were removed.